# How to use PictureBox with MDI form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox, mdichild, mdiparent

I have an MDI windows form and many child windows forms in vb.net. What exactly done that the Mdi form have a PictureBox control over it. If I call a child form from mdi form then PictureBox of MDI form overlap the child form mean it hides the child form behind the PictureBox of MDI windows form.

How to send PictureBox behind windows forms?

[image: This image describes the problem]

Comment: Show the code that produces that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i approached the situation. 
Since i am using a MDI-Parent Form and other Child Forms, I thought to Show() the picture box (pbImage.Show()) when the MDI Parent Control is doing nothing. If we open a new Child form, then we Hide() the pictureBox. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are some facts about MDI Container Form that you should know:

- The client area of the form is filled by `MdiClient` control which hosts all MDI children. So if you add a `Control` to the MDI parent, it will be located in front of the `MdiClient` and so it will be shown in front of MDI child forms.
- You can not add any control to `MdiClient` control. It just allow adding MDI child forms.
- To show a picture in MDI parent, you can set `BackgroundImage` and `BackgrroundImageLayout`, for example:

  ```
  Dim mdiClient = Me.Controls.OfType(Of MdiClient)().First()
  AddHandler mdiClient.Resize, Sub(s, a) mdiClient.Invalidate()
  Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.SomeImage
  Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
  ```

Comment: It seems the post answers your question. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.